# How to import custom QueryStringBindable in play 2.6

Tags: scala, playframework

I have written a QueryStringBindable for joda DateTime like this:

```
object Binders {
  val pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd"

  implicit object jodaDateTimeBinder extends QueryStringBindable.Parsing[DateTime] (
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern).parseDateTime, _.toString, (k: String, e: Exception) =>
      "Cannot parse %s as DateTime: %s".format(k, e.getMessage())
  )
}
```

and I am importing it in build.sbt

```
routesImport += "com.xyz.utils._"
```

but during compilation I am still getting errors:

No QueryString binder found for type org.joda.time.DateTime. Try to implement an implicit QueryStringBindable for this type.

Can anyone point out what's wrong here?

Comment: `routesImport += "com.xyz.utils._"`
is not the same thing as `routesImport += "com.xyz.utils.Binders._"`

Answer (score 3):

I think I had a similar issue with ZonedDateTime. I had to add the imports to build.sbt. Perhaps you can try the same with org.joda.time.DateTime.

```
routesImport ++= Seq(
  "utils.Binders._",
  "java.sql.Date",
  "java.time.LocalDate",
  "java.time.ZonedDateTime",
  "model.dto._"
)
```